# Looking for Reactor Pattern example source code in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, reactor

Just read Douglas R. Schmidt’s paper on the reactor pattern and I'd like to see a good example actually implemented to clear some questions up.  I spent some time searching for a fully implemented example but haven't been able to find one.  If someone's already implemented this and is willing to share the code that would be greatly appreciated. Or, of course, a link to an example in C++ would be great as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find working examples of the Reactor pattern implementation in the, freely available, source of the ACE framework, developed by Douglas R. Schmidt: http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html

In his book "C++ Network Programming, Volume 2: Systematic Reuse with ACE and Frameworks" Douglas R. Schmidt gives detailed explanation of the implementation of the Logger example project (included in ACE), both implemented as a Reactor and Proactor if I remember correctly - but I read the book a few years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/async.html)

Comment: I saw that but it's the proactor pattern, which I agree will be good to look at in terms of it's similarity to the reactor pattern, but I'm still looking for a pure reactor pattern.  Mainly because I think it will be easier to understand before moving onto the proactor pattern.